# How do you round a decimal number in C sharp?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write some code that converts Pound Sterling to US Dollars. 
The converter tool works fine. However, I am struggling with rounding the decimal numbers.
So for example, when I convert £24.50, my tool outputs $31.8500 when I want it to output $31.75.
I have experimented with the Math.Round(); method but unfortunately I haven't failed to get my desired result.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace currencyconverter
{
public partial class currencyconv : Form
{


    decimal US_Dollars = Math.Round(1.30m,2);
    decimal Australian_Dollars = 1.87m;
    decimal European_Euros = 1.17m;



    public currencyconv() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void currencyconv_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cmbcurrency.Text = "Select a currency";

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbcurrency.SelectedIndex == -1 || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtconvert.Text)))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.");

        }

        else
            {
            decimal British_Pound = decimal.Parse(txtconvert.Text);
            if (cmbcurrency.Text == "USD")
            {
                txtresult.Text = System.Convert.ToString(("$" + British_Pound * US_Dollars));
            }

            if (cmbcurrency.Text == "AUD")
            {

                txtresult.Text = System.Convert.ToString(("$" + British_Pound * Australian_Dollars));
            }

            if (cmbcurrency.Text == "EUR")
            {

                txtresult.Text = System.Convert.ToString(("€" + British_Pound * European_Euros));
            }
        }
    }

    private void txtconvert_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Char chr = e.KeyChar;
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numerical value.");
        }

        if(e.KeyChar == '.' && (txtconvert.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)){

            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: How is 31.8500 *rounded* to 31.75? This are whole 10 cents less...

Comment: How does that explain your unusual rounding?

Comment: my converter is outputting an usual rounding, this is why i posted this question to stop that.

Comment: You should define what you actually mean by "rounding" then. In words or a formula, not just by two value that can be related in a lot of ways.

Comment: im new here. give me a break.

Comment: Well, you want an answer that solves your problem. That would require to understand what your actual expectations are. And only you can explain them. That's got nothing to do with being new anywhere or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following to get the specific $31.75. You will need to use 1.296 as the rate to convert pound to USD.

```
    decimal US_Dollars = 1.296m;

    Console.WriteLine("$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", (decimal)24.50 * US_Dollars));
    // output: $31.75
```

In your code, you will use the following

```
    if (cmbcurrency.Text == "USD")
    {
        txtresult.Text = System.Convert.ToString("$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", British_Pound * US_Dollars));
    }
```

**Recommendation:** Use a web api to pull the rate instead of hardcoding the number for conversion. [This is one example:](https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP)

This code is to use the API to get the correct conversion rate

```
    public static double GetRate(string baseFormat, string resultFormat)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient($"https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base={baseFormat}"); // CHange the base to whichever you are converting
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var rates = JObject.Parse(response.Content)["rates"];
        return double.Parse(rates[resultFormat].ToString());
    }

    //Usage
    double US_Dollars = GetRate("GBP", "USD");
    Console.WriteLine("$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", (double)24.50 * US_Dollars));


// output: $31.74
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly! However, now, my conversion isn't matching the output produced by Google currency converter. For example, when I convert 24.50GBP to USD, my converter says 31.85USD whereas Google says 31.75USD

Comment: I added a recommendation. Try that. You will need to change from decimal to double as welll

Comment: When i convert it on google, i get 31.74 which is precisely what I get when i use Double instead of decimal.

Comment: Added the code for you to run through. You can use a method to look up the latest currency rate as well (this is just an example of what you can do)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is to take your converted number and use String.Format, something like this:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);
```

First parameter is the format you would like to have, and the second one is the value you want to translate to the given format.

I guess this is what you need.

Comment: thank you for your response, where in the code would I place this?

Comment: Wherever you get the converted quantity. I mean, if you want to convert from Pounds to US Dollars, once you get the converted number, and you want to display it, there is where you should write the above code.